# Add 5 minutes to timestamp after each model insert using Factory

Tags: laravel

When inserting models into the database I'd like to add 5 minutes to the `timestamp` property after each single model insert.

I thought that using `Sequence` like this would do the trick but it's not working: all models that are inserted still have the same timestamp.

```php
namespace Database\Seeders;

use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\Sequence;

class TestSeeder extends Seeder
{
    public function run()
    {
        \App\Models\Test::factory(1000)
           ->state(new Sequence(
             fn () => ['timestamp' => now()->addMinutes(5)->toDateTimeString()],
           ))
           ->create();
    }
}
```

Comment: Not an right answer, but this may help you `now()->addMinutes($faker->numberBetween( 1, 8 ))->toDateTimeString()`

Comment: Indeed not the right answer :-). That will give random timestamps, I need the timestamp to increase by 5 minutes for each subsequent insert.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will suggest this approach maybe with the need for some adjustments:

```
class TestSeeder extends Seeder
{
    private $testData = [];

    public function run()
    {
        $now = now();
        for ($i=0; $i < 100; $i++) {
            $testData[] = [
                'key1' => Str::random(10),
                'key2' => Str::random(10),
                'timestamp' => $now->addMinutes(5)->toDateTimeString()
            ];
        }
        foreach ($testData as $test) {
            \App\Models\Test::create($test);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: \App\Models\Test::create($testData);  multiple insert ; this approach is good too

Comment: I ended up using this and instead of the `foreach` loop I used `Test::insert($testData)`. Also: this code works about 100 times faster than using a Factory...!

Answer (score 1):

Use Factory Callbacks;

```
class TestFactory extends Factory
 {
   
    protected $model = Test::class;

    /**
     * Configure the model factory.
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function configure()
    {
        return $this->afterCreating(function (Test $test) {
           $test->update(['created_at' => Test::last()->created_at->addMinutes(5)]);
        });
    }
}
```

Seeder Class

```
public function run()
    {
        \App\Models\Test::factory(1000)->create();
    }
```

Comment: Looks like this should work. I get `Call to undefined method App\Models\Test::last()` but I assume you meant `latest()`. In order to make that quicker I used `'timestamp' => Test::orderBy('id', 'desc')->first()->timestamp->addMinutes(5)->toDateTimeString()` but it still doesn't work: all timestamps have the same value.

Answer (score -2):

You can use Eloquent Model Events: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#events

**Ex:**

```
class User extends Model
{
/**
 * The "booted" method of the model.
 *
 * @return void
 */
protected static function booted()
{
    static::created(function ($user) {
        // update the time or any fields else
    });
}
}
```

Comment: This is a really bad idea as it will execute the logic in `created` *every time* a model is created. I only want it to happen when using a factory (eg when *seeding* the database or running tests).